# How to set Viewbox content based on DataTrigger

Tags: wpf

I've video player with two button: Play and Pause.
I want to use only one button. when user clicks on Play, the button appearance will changed to Pause and vice versa.

What is the better approach to achieve that task **without** using cs code behind?

I've tried to use DataTrigger to my `IsPlaying` property, but with no much success....

Here is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Viewbox x:Key="viewboxSource" >
            <Viewbox.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPlaying}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Path">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Path Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="1" Fill="AliceBlue">
                                <Path.Data>
                                    <GeometryGroup>
                                        <EllipseGeometry Center="100,100" RadiusX="100" RadiusY="100"/>
                                    </GeometryGroup>
                                </Path.Data>
                            </Path>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Viewbox.Triggers>
        </Viewbox>
    </Window.Resources>
      <StackPanel>
        <Button Content="{StaticResource viewboxSource}"></Button>
     </StackPanel>
```

But I gut an error that says " 'Path' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name  "     .
Can anyone can help or give me a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

These kind of behaviour fits toggle button patern.

Make a style in your resources

```
       <Style x:Key="PlayToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" >
```

and then define a templeate in it

```
            <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
```

What is the most important here is to use VisualStateManager.

```
                       <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" />
                                        <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2" To="#FF392929" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I use 2 animation. One moves button for 2 pixels and second change the gradient which gives a nice experience.

The only drawback is you need to use storyboards to handle these states. You need to add a Path  object which I called Geometry nad mainupulate it.

```
            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Geometry" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Data">
              <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value=""/> <!-- place the data here (how your button looks like) -->
              </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
```

**But** IMHO the better solution is to place 2 Path object in the template that on is over another and change the opacity of the top-most one.

```
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="TopGeometry" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.0">
            <DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
                <QuadraticEase EasingMode="EaseIn"/>
            </DoubleAnimation.EasingFunction>
        </DoubleAnimation>
    </Storyboard>
```

You would have a nice transition between these two states. What is more, no data is needed f.e IsPLaying property.